# Jquery Validation plugin not working in laravel

Tags: jquery, laravel

I am using a jquery validation plugin in laravel project. I have added validation in one form. For this form, we can go from 2 different routes for the same form. If I am going through the POST method jquery validation will work If I am going through the GET method it is not working.

here my routes

```
Route::post('/searchparentdetails','StudentController@search')->middleware('permission:Add-Student');  
// from this route it will working 


Route::get('addstudent/{id}','ParentController@addstudent')->name('addstudent');

//from this route it will not working
```

here are my controllers

```
public function search(Request $request){

    $this->validate($request,[
        'parentmobile' => 'required'
    ]);
    $ids = Academic::select('id')->active()->first();

    $mob = $request->input('parentmobile');

    $parent = DB::table('parent_names')->where('mobile',$mob)->where('academic_id',$ids->id)->count();

    if($parent > 0)
    {
        $course = Course::all();
        $parentdetails = DB::table('parent_names')->where('mobile',$mob)
         ->where('academic_id',$ids->id)->first();
        return view('students.create',compact('parentdetails','course'));

    }

}


public function addstudent($id)
{
    $course = Course::all();
    $parentdetails = ParentName::find($id);
    return view('students.create',compact('parentdetails','course'));

}
```

form

```
<form method="post" id="studentform"  action="{{ url('storestudent') }}">
<input type="hidden" name="parentid" value="<?php echo $parentdetails->id ?>" >
  {{ csrf_field() }}


  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <p class="topheading">School Details</p>
    </div>
      <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-4">
                   Admission to class
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-8">
                 <select class="form-control" name="course" id="course_name">
                     <option disabled selected>Select</option>
                     @foreach($course as $cou)
                  <option value="{{$cou->id}}">{{$cou->course_name}}</option>
                     @endforeach
                 </select>
              </div>
            </div>

           </div>
         </div>

   <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Add">
</div>
```

validation file

```
   $('#studentform').validate({
       rules: {
            course: {
                required:true,

            },
    });
```

Comment: What is the error? Whats happening exactly? Can you show form?

Comment: it is going to the controller directly  without validating

Comment: wait I will add form

Comment: What kind validation you have done? How should it work?

Comment: I want validation like  this field  is required validation

Comment: For validation you can use `required` in html tag of that field or `parsley.js`.

Comment: I am using a JS file you can check I have updated my question. My problem is it is working If I am going through  post method that is searchparentdetails and it is not working if I am going through get method that is  addstudent

Comment: did you added validation `js` file to both pages?

Comment: it only one page. but I am accessing from 2 different routes